# Outermeasure and $\mu^{*}$-measurable sets proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $\mu^{*}$ is an outer measure on $X$ and $\{A_j\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of disjoint $\mu^{*}$-measurable sets, then for every $E\subset X$ $$\mu^{*}\left(E\cap\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}A_j\right)\right) = \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu^{*}(E\cap A_j)$$

proof: Let $\{A_j\}_{1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of disjoint $\mu^{*}$-measurable sets and $E\subset X$. Set, $$A = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty} A_j$$ Since $A$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable then we have $$\mu^{*}(E) \geq \mu^{*}(E\cap A) + \mu^{*}(E\cap A^{c}) \ \  \forall E\subset X, \  \mu(E) < \infty$$ $$ = \mu^{*}\left(E\cap\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}A_j\right)\right) + \mu^{*}\left(E\cap\left(\bigcap_{1}^{\infty}A_j^{c}\right)\right)$$ I am not sure if my approach will yield the desired result, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You write "If $A$ is $\mu^{\ast}$-measurable". It is, since the family $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mu^{\ast}$-measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra. Is that known, or is this part of the proof that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: It is known, since it is stated in the problem. Ill delete the if part

Comment: Okay. By measurability (and disjointness) of the $A_j$, you have $$\mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E\cap \bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty A_j\Biggr) = \mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E \cap \bigcup_{j = n+1}^\infty A_j\Biggr) + \sum_{j = 1}^n \mu^{\ast}(E\cap A_j)$$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ok, where to you go from there then. If you know could you prove an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the $\sigma$-subadditivity of outer measures, we have

$$\mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E \cap \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr) \leqslant \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \mu^{\ast}(E\cap A_j).$$

Since the $A_j$ are $\mu^{\ast}$-measurable and disjoint, we have

\begin{align}
\mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E \cap \bigcup_{j = n}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr) &= \mu^{\ast}\Biggl(\Biggl(E\cap \bigcup_{j = n}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr)\cap A_n\Biggr) + \mu^{\ast}\Biggl(\Biggl(E\cap \bigcup_{j = n}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr)\setminus A_n\Biggr)\\
&= \mu^{\ast}(E\cap A_n) + \mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E\cap \bigcup_{j = n+1}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr)
\end{align}

and hence

$$\mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E\cap \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr) = \mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E\cap \bigcup_{j = n+1}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr) + \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \mu^{\ast} (E\cap A_j)$$

for all $n$. Since $\mu^{\ast}(B) \geqslant 0$ for all sets $B$, that implies

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n} \mu^{\ast}(E\cap A_j) \leqslant \mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E\cap \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr)$$

for all $n$. By definition of the sum of an infinite series,

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \mu^{\ast}(E\cap A_j) \leqslant \mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E\cap \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr).$$

Comment: Why do you mention $\mu^{*}(B) \geq 0$ for all sets $B$. Given that how does the next implication make sense?

Comment: @MorganWeiss We have an equality $X = Y + Z$. Using $Y \geqslant 0$, we deduce $Z \leqslant X$. Where $X$ is the outer measure of the big set, $Z$ is the finite sum, and $Y$ is the outer measure of the smaller set.

Comment: @hermes Induction. First do it for $n = 1$, then for $n = 2$ etc.

Comment: @hermes $$\mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E \cap \bigcup_{j = n+2}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr) = \mu^{\ast}(E \cap A_{n+2}) + \mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E \cap \bigcup_{j = n+3}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr)$$ by $\mu^{\ast}$-measurability of $A_{n+2}$.

Comment: @hermes That is split off in $$\mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E \cap \bigcup_{j = n+1}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr) = \mu^{\ast}(E\cap A_{n+1}) + \mu^{\ast}\Biggl(E \cap \bigcup_{j = n+2}^{\infty} A_j\Biggr).$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $E\cap (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j})\in 2^{X}$ defined for any arbitrary $E\subset X$. Since $A_{j}$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable $\forall j\in \mathbb{N}$, by definition of $\mu^{*}$-measurable (i.e., $\mu^{*}(E) = \mu^{*}(E\cap A)+\mu^{*}(E\cap A^{c}$) for all $E\subset X$) we can state the following:

$$\mu^{*}(E\cap (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j})) = \mu^{*}(E\cap (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j})\cap A_{1}) + \mu^{*}(E\cap (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j})\cap A_{1}^{c})$$ $$...= \mu^{*}(E\cap A_{1}) + \mu^{*}(E\cap (\bigcup_{j=2}^{\infty}A_{j})).$$
Noting that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu^{*}(E\cap (\bigcup_{j=n}^{\infty}A_{j})) = \mu^{*}(E\cap\varnothing) = \mu^{*}(\varnothing) = 0$, it's easy to see (via induction) $\mu^{*}(E\cap (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j})) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu^{*}(E\cap A_{j}). \blacksquare$

---

Aside: possibly worth noting is whether $\mu^{*}(E\cap (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j})$ can be considered "well-defined." Seeing that $E\cap (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j})$ is an element of the power set $2^{X}$ and all outer-measures necessarily need be defined for all subsets of X (given we're dealing with an outer-measure defined for X), we can indeed say that $\mu^{*}(E\cap (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j})$ maps to a "well-defined" value.